# Scale bars (SEM-Zeiss)

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, distance, microscopy, scales

I am using ImageJ to measure distances in an SEM image. The scale bar I'm using looks like this
[image]

What is the correct distance represented by the scale bar? Is it line 1 or 2?

Comment: Why don't you use something less ambiguous?

Comment: One way to deal with this is to treat the width of the sidebars as a systematic fractional uncertainty in your measurements.